# Document changes to italics without command

Tags: fonts

So I'm working on a math paper, and after writing a number of examples, the plain text I am using to describe some phenomenon changed to italics.  How do I get the document to write using the default font?[image]

You can see the italics start under 0.1.2 Preliminaries.  Here is the code for the paper

> ```
> \documentclass[]{book}
>
> %These tell TeX which packages to use.
> \usepackage{array,epsfig}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{amsfonts}
> \usepackage{amssymb}
> \usepackage{amsxtra}
> \usepackage{amsthm}
> \usepackage{mathrsfs}
> \usepackage{color}
>
> %Here I define some theorem styles and shortcut commands for symbols I use often
> \theoremstyle{definition}
> \newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
> \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
> \newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
> \newtheorem*{rmk}{Remark}
> \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
> \newtheorem*{joke}{Joke}
> \newtheorem{ex}{Example}
> \newtheorem*{soln}{Solution}
> \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
>
> \newcommand{\lra}{\longrightarrow}
> \newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
> \newcommand{\surj}{\twoheadrightarrow}
> \newcommand{\graph}{\mathrm{graph}}
> \newcommand{\bb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
> \newcommand{\Z}{\bb{Z}}
> \newcommand{\Q}{\bb{Q}}
> \newcommand{\R}{\bb{R}}
> \newcommand{\C}{\bb{C}}
> \newcommand{\N}{\bb{N}}
> \newcommand{\M}{\mathbf{M}}
> \newcommand{\m}{\mathbf{m}}
> \newcommand{\MM}{\mathscr{M}}
> \newcommand{\HH}{\mathscr{H}}
> \newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}
> \newcommand{\Ho}{\in\HH(\Om)}
> \newcommand{\bd}{\partial}
> \newcommand{\del}{\partial}
> \newcommand{\bardel}{\overline\partial}
> \newcommand{\textdf}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}\index{#1}}
> \newcommand{\img}{\mathrm{img}}
> \newcommand{\ip}[2]{\left\langle{#1},{#2}\right\rangle}
> \newcommand{\inter}[1]{\mathrm{int}{#1}}
> \newcommand{\exter}[1]{\mathrm{ext}{#1}}
> \newcommand{\cl}[1]{\mathrm{cl}{#1}}
> \newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
> \newcommand{\vol}{\mathrm{vol}}
> \newcommand{\cnt}{\mathrm{ct}}
> \newcommand{\osc}{\mathrm{osc}}
> \newcommand{\LL}{\mathbf{L}}
> \newcommand{\UU}{\mathbf{U}}
> \newcommand{\support}{\mathrm{support}}
> \newcommand{\AND}{\;\wedge\;}
> \newcommand{\OR}{\;\vee\;}
> \newcommand{\Oset}{\varnothing}
> \newcommand{\st}{\ni}
> \newcommand{\wh}{\widehat}
>
> %Pagination stuff.
> \setlength{\topmargin}{-.3 in}
> \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
> \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
> \setlength{\textheight}{9.in}
> \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
> \pagestyle{empty}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{center}
> {\Large Hypergeometric Bernoulli Numbers via Umbral Calculus}\\
> \textbf{Christopher Ernst}\\ %You should put your name here
> Begun: 5-5-2017 %You should write the date here.
> \end{center}
>
> \vspace{0.2 cm}
>
> \section{Introduction}
>
> \subsection{Preliminaries - Action of a Formal Power Series on Polynomials}
>
> Let $f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{a_j\frac{t^j}{j!}}\in \mathcal{F}$ be a formal power series where $a_j\in \mathbb{F}$ where $char(\mathbb{F})=0$ and let $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_kx^k}\in P$, the algebra of polynomials of a single variable over $\mathbb{C}$.  We know then that $P^*$ is the vector space of all linear functionals on $P$.  The notation 
>
> $$ \langle L \mid p(x) \rangle $$
>
> is used to denote the action of a linear functional $L$ on a polynomial $p(x)$.  As $P^*$ is a vector space, we have by linearity that for linear functionals $L$ and $M$ and field elements $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, 
>
> $$ \langle aL+bM \mid p(x) \rangle = a\langle L \mid p(x) \rangle + b\langle M \mid p(x) \rangle $$
>
> It is important then to note that since linear functionals are uniquely determined by the action on a basis, we know that $L$ is uniquely determined by the sequence of constants $ \langle L \mid x^n \rangle $.
>
> The formal power series $f$ defined above defines a linear functional on $P$ if we define the following;
>
> \begin{equation} \langle f(t) \mid x^n \rangle = a_n \end{equation}
>
> for all nonnegative integers.  Thus, the formal power series $t^k$ gives
>
> $$\langle t^j \mid x^n \rangle=n!\delta_{n,j}$$
>
> where $\delta_{n,j}$ is the Kronecker delta.  Something to take note of then is that any linear functional $L\in P^*$ has the form of $f(t)$.  If then
>
> \begin{equation}
> f_L(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty {\langle L \mid x^j \rangle}\frac{t^j}{j!}
> \end{equation}
>
> we have that $f_L(t)=L$ as linear functionals.  Defining a map $L\rightarrow f_L(t)$, it can be shown this map is a vector space isomorphism and we can now think of linear functionals as formal power series.  
>
> Let $$h(t)=f(t)+g(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{a_j\frac{t^j}{j!}}+\sum_{j=0}^\infty{b_j\frac{t^j}{j!}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{(a_j+b_j)\frac{t^j}{j!}}$$  and $$ j(t)=f(t)g(t)=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty{a_j\frac{t^j}{j!}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty{b_j\frac{t^j}{j!}}\right)= \sum_{j=0}^\infty\left[\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{j}{i}a_ib_{j-i}\right]\frac{t^j}{j!}$$
>
> Then
>
> \begin{equation} \langle h(t) \mid x^n \rangle = a_n+b_n \end{equation}
>
> and
>
> \begin{equation} \langle j(t) \mid x^n \rangle = \sum_{i=0}^j\binom{j}{i}a_ib_{j-i} \end{equation}
>
> Noticing then the relationship between the formal power series have with the linear functionals, we can show then that 
>
> \begin{equation}
> \langle f+g \mid x^n \rangle = \langle f \mid x^n \rangle + \langle g \mid x^n \rangle
> \end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation}
> \langle fg \mid x^n \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\langle f \mid x^k \rangle \langle g \mid x^{n-k} \rangle
> \end{equation}
>
> and it is these operations that allow us to extend our vector space idea and can now label $\mathcal{F}$ as an algebra structure.  In fact, this structure is known as the \it{umbral algebra}.
>
> \begin{ex}
> $f(t)=e^{yt}$
>
> $$\langle e^{yt}\mid x^n \rangle =\left\langle \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(yt)^j}{j!} \middle| x^n\right\rangle=\left\langle \sum_{j=0}^\infty y^j\frac{t^j}{j!} \middle| x^n\right\rangle=y^n$$
>
> and
>
> $$\langle e^{yt} \mid p(x) \rangle = \left\langle e^{yt} \middle| \sum_{k=0}^nc_kx^k \right\rangle=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_k}\langle  e^{yt} \mid x^k \rangle=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_k}y^k=p(y)$$
>
> \end{ex}
>
> \begin{ex}
> $g(t)=f'(t)$
>
> $$\langle g(t) \mid x^n \rangle =\langle f'(t) \mid x^n \rangle =\left\langle \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j\frac{t^j}{j!} \middle| x^n\right\rangle=\left\langle \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{j+1}\frac{t^j}{j!} \middle| x^n\right\rangle=a_{n+1}$$
> \end{ex}
>
> \begin{prop}
> $$\langle f^{(k)}(x) \mid x^n \rangle=a_{n+k}$$
> \end{prop}
>
> \begin{ex}
> $f(t)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$
>
> Note that
>
> $$\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{x^{j-1}}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{(j+1)!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{(j+1)}}\frac{x^j}{j!}$$
>
> Therefore, 
>
> $$\left\langle \frac{e^x-1}{x} \middle| x^n \right\rangle = \frac{1}{n+1}$$
> \end{ex}
>
> \begin{ex}
> $f(t)=\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$
>
> Note that
>
> $$\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{x^{j-2}}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{(j+2)!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{(j+2)(j+1)}}\frac{x^j}{j!}$$
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$\left\langle \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \middle| x^n \right\rangle = \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$
> \end{ex}
>
> \begin{prop}
> It makes sense then that if $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial
>
> $$T_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{x^j}{j!}$$ 
>
> then
>
> $$\left\langle \frac{e^x-T_{k-1}(x)}{x^k} \middle| x^n \right\rangle = \frac{1}{(n+k)_k}$$
>
> where $(n+k)_k=(n+k)(n+k-1)...(n+2)(n+1)$
> \end{prop}
>
> \begin{ex}
> Replacing $x^n$ with an arbitrary polynomials $p(x)=c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n$
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \left\langle \frac{e^x-1}{x} \middle|   p(x) \right\rangle &=& >\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1}{x} \middle| c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n \right\rangle \\ >&=&c_0\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1}{x} \middle| 1 \right\rangle+c_1\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1}{x} \middle| x \right\rangle+...+c_n\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1}{x} \middle| x^n \right\rangle \\ &=&\frac{c_0}{1}+\frac{c_1}{2}+...+\frac{c_n}{n+1} \\ &=&\int_0^1[c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n]dx \\ &=&\int_0^1p(x)dx
> \end{eqnarray*}
> \end{ex}
>
> \begin{ex}
>
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \left\langle \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \middle|   p(x) \right\rangle &=& 
> \left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \middle| c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n \right\rangle \\ 
> &=&c_0\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \middle| 1 \right\rangle+c_1\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \middle| x \right\rangle+...+c_n\left\langle
> \frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2} \middle| x^n \right\rangle \\ &=&\frac{c_0}{1\cdot  2}
> +\frac{c_1}{2\cdot 3}+...+\frac{c_n}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\ >&=&\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1(c_0+c_1y+...+c_ny^n)dy\right]dx \\ &=&\int_0^1\int_0^1p(y)dydx
> \end{eqnarray*}
> \end{ex}
>
>
> \begin{prop}
> $$\left\langle \frac{e^x-T_{k-1}(x)}{x^k} \middle|   p(x) \right\rangle =\underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1}_{k\text{ times}}p(x_1)dx_1dx_2...dx$$
> \end{prop}
>
> \subsection{Preliminaries - Formal Power Series as Linear Operators}
>
> Let 
>
> \begin{equation} t^kx^n=(n)_kx^{n-k}
> \end{equation}
>
> It is clear that $t^k$ then acts as the $k$-th derivative on the monomial $x^n$.  Now if we consider a formal power series acting on $x^n$, we see that
>
>
> \end{document}
> ```

EDIT:  I know this is probably frowned upon, but I put the whole code up.  I'm relatively new to TeX and what I learned was on my own, never formally taught, so I'm having trouble finding where the issue is based upon the responses I've seen.  I'm sorry if I have violated any rules by doing so..

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  how is this input?  if the preliminaries are within the scope of "proposition" (assuming that this is defined as a theorem-style object), then any text within that scope will be italic.  we need to see your input code -- preferably a small compilable example that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}' and produces the anomalous output.

Comment: Do please show the code that gives rise to Proposition 3 and the material shortly before and after the header line that's numbered 0.1.2.

Comment: This is the same bug as the one in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399010/problem-with-beamer-text-gets-stuck-in-a-certain-font.  Follow that question because its solution should work for you also.

Comment: Sorry.  I will produce the code when I get home.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know my example was a large amount of code, but I'm not sure still how to fix.

Comment: You really need to unlearn a lot of stuff. Most of those blank lines should not be there, never use `$$...$$` or `eqnarray`. You error is using `\it{...}`, (1) `\it` should never be used, (2) it is a switch, ie does not take arguments and thus affects the rest of the doc. Use `\emph{...}` to emphasize instead. I would suggest consulting a introdution on LaTeX, Nicola Talbot writes some good ones.

Comment: The blank lines always helped me find my work, help separate ideas, etc.  Again, I basically taught myself by looking at past papers my professors worked on.  Thank you for the help.  Where was the "\it" in the code, I can not find it?

Comment: Nevermind, @daleif.  I found the \it command.  Thank you.  I will DEFINTELY consult the book you recommend.

Comment: Remember, blank lines mark new paragraphs, ever wondered why so much of your text starts indented. Just start the lines that does not mark a new paragraph by a `%`, then latex ignores that line.