# Problem with beamer: text gets stuck in a certain font

Tags: fonts

I had a problem with ${\mathbf{}}$ persisting, even after I close the $\mathbf$ tag.  Looking at my advisor's template, I inserted a certain line which made it stop doing that-- but then, trying to switch to blackboard bold made the font bold instead.  This didn't happen before I inserted my advisor's line.  What can I do to un-bolden the remaining font?  Probably something like a font reset...

Minimal (non-)working example:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}

% custom definition of \Cal, to use variations of symbols not readily available in other pkgs
% see below for printscreen at bottom of post illustrating one of the differences.
\newfam\calfam
\font\bbbten=msbm10
\font\bbbseven=msbm7
\font\bbbfive=msbm5
\font\calten=eusm10
\font\calseven=eusm7
\font\calfive=eusm5
\textfont\calfam=\calten
\scriptfont\calfam=\calseven
\scriptscriptfont\calfam=\calfive
\def\Cal{\fam=\calfam}

% moving the next line to the top of the file results in a third type of font stuck-ing
\documentclass{beamer}

% advisor's line; try compiling with and without it, to see the different problems
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifsmall,stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\mathbb Q$ {\textbf{gen}} $\mathbb Q$ ${\mathbf{gen}}$ $\mathbb Q$ $asdf$

$\backslash$Cal O: $\Cal O$; $\backslash$mathcal O: $\mathcal O$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: just to elaborate on the one-line comment at the top of my file:  using `\mathcal` results in a different font of O, which is not acceptable for what I am doing:

[image]

Comment: i haven't tested this, but the way you're defining the fonts is proper for plain tex, but not for latex.  better to use a latex package.  for `\mathbb{...}`, `\usepackage{amsfonts}` would be appropriate; for the calligraphic font, `\usepackage{eucal}` and then `\mathcal{...}` should give the desired result.  (and i've never heard of `\usefonttheme[...]{serif}` although that may just be my relative unfamiliarity with `beamer` options.)

Comment: also this works: `\documentclass{beamer}

% advisor's line; try compiling with and without it, to see the different problems
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifsmall,stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$\mathbb{Q}$  \textbf{gen}  $\mathbb{Q}$  $\mathbf{gen}$ $\mathbb{Q}$ $asdf$
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Barbara,
I've elaborated on the one-line comment at the top of my file-- namely, on why using $\mathcal$ will not work for this example, but rather I have to define my own font.

Comment: @Zarko Yeah, unfortunately I do need that font defined, to be used in another part of my document; see updated post on why.

Comment: @Alex -- try `\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}`.  that redefines `\mathcal` to use the euler script instead of the cm calligraphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to produce the result you've asked for:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% advisor's line; try compiling with and without it, to see the different problems
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifsmall,stillsansseriflarge]{serif}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\mathbb Q$ {\textbf{gen}} $\mathbb Q$ ${\mathbf{gen}}$ $\mathbb Q$ $asdf$

\texttt{\char`\\mathcal\{O\}}: $\mathcal{O}$

\texttt{\char`\\mathscr\{O\}}: $\mathscr{O}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: But then how would I get the other style of O in my paper?  I need both...

Comment: @Alex -- you didn't say that you needed both.  see updated answer.